# React Native - cannot access data from Array inside Array from json file

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, loops, google-maps

So I have typical json result from Google maps api

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CqQCFgEAAL2fPrvHrkhgi11wNUC40-FEYJ93rH1Bo9FRkqxMfMlvqaEQv6hgiLoJXmeFBFMA6Uw-kcECgRXs_VzE6QVNPMRTrh402Z9Rn1dUVC_2B3WwopG_KNcftFARDQZD0K-a7swHAb_jftghftWtzrTqa8GTKMKuLCHS6ZJooPXOGpndn1h2yYO7bIF4GiPE80HgaLrgZDAJ-bf71LXhWmvmPtPiU0UGZeH1Zp4945yS5PHK1WVCMPoIR2XVqv9d9k08ZKqQPtnNOS1YsvdZOaY1Jy76eFIhCMFr1yhR0GyBmtVs6_wf9yEdi-SXSjqiciD77bk9pKf2p4b8C_9jhY3SJvB9wgLGUbDS0Y3gFG63EHcMKva4FVHFiov-7_abNk3i3RIQGSQOIFfRj3zZaSVngR8PcRoUa9z0FhpaicLUkREG-VRpE_wUZhE",
   "results" : [
      {
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_recreational-71.png",
         "name" : "Park Leśny Zdroje",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3024,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103847965103971799822\"\u003eKSD\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAHvmblqXHuIBST9cZZI3yLtIuay_of90rDBUOoBQ64Luh7U_bVFTK5jhliXE9pFhRWMZjw4yHJXOFbxKQYBmEJwvBLNXkQGZrr5CvjlPT0HBHKququkGzjA8JJvbIdVC4EhCX_9SFH1F88ezn0N9XUaEfGhQpUDqAXZzLaSn0rrIIdMFwjCz6yA",
               "width" : 4032
            }
         ],
      },
]
```

And i cannot somehow access photo_reference from array photos.

```
                {parks.results.map((element,index)=>
                    <View key={index} style={AppStyle.mapCard}>
                        <View style={AppStyle.mapCardImg}>
//Tried this
                            <Text>{element.photos.map(item => item.photo_reference)}</Text>
//and this
<Text> {element.photos.photo_reference} </Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={AppStyle.mapCardDescription}>
                            <Text>{element.name}</Text>
                                <Text>
                                    ({element.rating})
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
```

I know it's array in array and i need to iterate through it but it doesnt work.
This way: {element.photos.map(item => item.photo_reference)} **i have undefined is not an object(evaluating element.photos.map)**

This way  {element.photos.photo_reference}  **undefined is not an object**

Whats the solution in react Native?

Comment: Can you please add the code ```<Text>{console.log('photos', element.photos)}</Text>``` before ```<Text>{element.photos.map(item => item.photo_reference)}</Text>``` (comment this line) just to check what your ```photos``` array is?

Comment: so i got: 
`photos Array [
  Object {
    "height": 3024,
    "html_attributions": Array [
      "ahrefblabla",
    ],
    "photo_reference": "blabla",
    "width": 4032,
  },
]
`

Comment: for each results element of course

Comment: try to loop your array conditionaly: 
```<Text>{element.photos && element.photos.map(item => item.photo_reference)}</Text>```

Comment: Yeah. Did this already with another component checking every element i want to show from json file and conditions. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps Api is not always returning every property of single Place. Error was that some places doesn't have photos so there's no array in json. The same about rating and others.

Adding conditions to check if variable exists solves problem.

element.photos && element.photos.map(item => item.photo_reference)